# Timer in Tkinter is imprecise

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

I've created a Python program with Tkinter which, among other things, runs a timer counting up. After a few iterations, I settled on a timer thread that wakes on response to an event, triggered by a button press. The timer thread updates the timer label, and then sleeps for one second before doing it again.

I figured that sleeping for one second would lead to the timer being too slow, as the code execution itself would also be taking time, so I used the `time` module's `perf_counter()` to precisely measure the time the code execution took, and preemptively subtract that from the sleep time. In theory, this should work, but on closer inspection, it still doesn't.

After as little as ten minutes of running, there are several seconds of drift away from a previously synchronized system time. Since this timer will often be running for hours at a time, these imprecisions can add up to a significant amount of error. As the system time shows, there is clearly nothing inherent to the OS preventing me from keeping time properly, so I'm really not sure what's going on. The code for the timer thread and a barebones container is shown below:

```
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from datetime import timedelta
import tkinter as tk
from _thread import start_new_thread
from threading import Event

class Timer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.timer_label = tk.Label(self, text="0:00:00", font='arial 40')
        self.timer_label.grid()
        tk.Button(self, text='start', command=self.timer_on).grid()
        self.timer_is_on = False
        self.timer_time = timedelta(seconds=0)
        start_new_thread(self.run_timer, ())

    def timer_on(self):
        self.timer_is_on = True
        self.timer.set()

    def run_timer(self):
        one_second = timedelta(seconds=1)
        while True:
            self.timer = Event()
            self.timer.wait()
            sleep(1)
            start = perf_counter()
            while self.timer_is_on:
                self.timer_time += one_second
                self.timer_label.config(text=str(self.timer_time))
                sleep(1 - (perf_counter() - start))
                start = perf_counter()

Timer().mainloop()
```

Comment: You're not using a tkinter timer (ie: `after`). You can probably reproduce this problem without tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, that's probably true. Are you saying I should remove the tkinter tag, then?